# React with TypeScript: Type is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I have a component in React that shows a pagination of products. I cannot figure out why I am getting this error when I'm trying to run the application:

> ```
> React with TypeScript: Type '{ postsPerPage: number; totalPosts: number; paginate: (pageNumber: number) => void; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ProductListProps'.   Property 'postsPerPage' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ProductListProps'.
> ```

My code:

```
const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
const [postsPerPage] = useState(10);
const indexOfLastPost = currentPage * postsPerPage;
const indexOfFirstPost = indexOfLastPost - postsPerPage;
const currentPosts = data.slice(indexOfFirstPost, indexOfLastPost);


const paginate = (pageNumber: number) => setCurrentPage(pageNumber);

return (
      <>
        <h1 className="headline">SHOP</h1>
        <div className="total">Total: ${totalPrice}</div>

        <ProductList products={data} onProductAddRequest={onProductAdded} posts={currentPosts}/>

        <Pagin postsPerPage={postsPerPage} totalPosts={data.length} paginate={paginate} />

     </>
```

My component look like this:

```
interface PaginProps {
    postsPerPage: number,
    totalPosts: number,
    paginate: (arg: number) => void
}

const Pagin = ( {postsPerPage, totalPosts, paginate}: PaginProps ) => {

    const pageNumbers = [];

    for (let i = 1; i <= Math.ceil (totalPosts / postsPerPage); i++) {
        pageNumbers.push(i);
    }

    const pageNum = pageNumbers.map(number => {
        return <div className='a page-item' key={number}><a className='a' onClick={() => paginate(number)} href="!#">{number}</a>
            </div>
    })

    return (<div className='pagin'>{pageNum}</div>)
} 

export default Pagin;
```

My `ProductListProps` look like this:

```
interface ProductListProps {
    products: ProductType[];
    posts: any[];
    onProductAddRequest: (product: ProductType) => void
}

interface ProductType {
    id: number;
    category: string;
    images?: string[];
    name: string;
    price: number;
    description?: string;
}
```

I can't find what's the problem here

Comment: I think we are missing some context of your app, because the error mentions a`ProductListProps` type which is nowhere to be seen. `IntrinsicAttributes` refers to in-built types of React components. This error seems like you have either mistyped a component's props somewhere.

Comment: if you'r not sending those values as props (i mean if those props are undefined ), just use them as optional , just use (?) in typescript as TS consider as mandatory (not optional) by default.

Comment: Mathieu , Shushanth Pallegar, I've edited my question with `ProductListProps`

Answer (score 7):

I don't see how `ProductListProps` is being used in your component, but I am thinking that the error occurs because you aren't exactly properly typing your component. The right way of doing so using typescript would be to use `React.FC` or `React.FunctionalComponent` (assuming you are one of the more recent React versions), and declare the interface as the generic type.

```
interface PaginProps {
    postsPerPage: number,
    totalPosts: number,
    paginate: (arg: number) => void
}

const Pagin: React.FC<PaginProps> = ({ postsPerPage, totalPosts, paginate }) => {

    const pageNumbers = [];

    for (let i = 1; i <= Math.ceil (totalPosts / postsPerPage); i++) {
        pageNumbers.push(i);
    }

    const pageNum = pageNumbers.map(number => {
        return <div className='a page-item' key={number}><a className='a' onClick={() => paginate(number)} href="!#">{number}</a>
            </div>
    })

    return (<div className='pagin'>{pageNum}</div>)
} 

export default Pagin;
```